# Can not use standard DEL key to access BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, bios

I am facing a weird issue with my computer. I suspect it to be Firmware bug but still seeking inputs.

I have Amazon Basics USB keyboard. Pressing the standard DEL key does not take me to BIOS. I need to press the other DEL key on 'Num Pad' section of the keyboard to access BIOS.

Board Gigabyte 880GM USB3 rev 3.1 Firmware FE (latest).
The standard DEL works absolutely fine after I reset the BIOS and as long as SATA Mode is IDE. The moment I switch to AHCI and save and boot into PC, the standard DEL key is now no longer effective to enter the BIOS, only the Num Pad Del Works.

The USB Legacy Mode is enabled in BIOS. I never had issues with PS/2 Keyboard.
I suspect it’s a firmware bug but still seeking any additional suggestions.
Both DEL keys otherwise work just fine.

Comment: "both Del keys"?? Surely one is Del, the other is actually Backspace? Only laptops share the functionality, extended keyboards delineate.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have 2 del keys too. One is below Insert, and the other one is shared with the . on the numpad.

Comment: There's a rule of thumb when it comes to computers and accessing the BIOS. If a computer has a PS/2 port, then its not always guaranteed that the keyboard is already initialized at boot due to various USB standards etc. In any case, a PS/2 keyboard should always work. There are ps/2 to usb convertors to use your current keyboard to test it out.

Comment: I'm looking at a selection of different extended keyboards right now... all have a Backspace key in amongst the qwerty, by the top numbers, & an *actual* Del key in with the Home/End etc above the arrow keys. Their functions are sometimes shared, but delineated for key aspects, for instance at boot. In Windows, the Backspace key won't trash a file, Del will.